# How authenticate with username, password and token in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate users in Django with username, password and token. All of them are stored in a database.

```
#accounts/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from account.forms import RegistrationForm, AccountAuthenticationForm

def login_view(request):      
    if request.POST:
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            token = request.POST['token']
            user = authenticate(username = username, password = password, token = token)

            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm()

    context['login_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', context)
```

```
#account/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, token, password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username')
        if not token:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a token')

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            token = token,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, token, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username = username,
            password = password,
            token = token,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Login is possible with the right username/password combination, but with the wrong token.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`authenticate` function perform query based on username and password and ignores token. That is the issue.

So solution is

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
......
if form.is_valid():
     username = request.POST['username']
     password = request.POST['password']
     token = request.POST['token']
     User = get_user_model()
     is_exists = User.objects.filter(username=username, token=token).exists()
     if is_exists:
       user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
       ......
     else:
         # Perform validation error invalid token or username.
```